# ESP8266 and spduino library printing weird caracters

Tags: rest, esp8266, arduino-uno

I am trying to use this example in arduino ide 2.2 to connect to an api:

I was trying to connect to a server in my VM and wanted to see if it worked, but can't

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <espduino.h>
#include <rest.h>

SoftwareSerial debugPort(2, 3); // RX, TX

ESP esp(&Serial, &debugPort, 4);

REST rest(&esp);

boolean wifiConnected = false;

void wifiCb(void* response)
{
  uint32_t status;
  RESPONSE res(response);

  if(res.getArgc() == 1) {
    res.popArgs((uint8_t*)&status, 4);
    if(status == STATION_GOT_IP) {
      debugPort.println("WIFI CONNECTED");
     
      wifiConnected = true;
    } else {
      wifiConnected = false;
    }
    
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  debugPort.begin(19200);
  esp.enable();
  delay(500);
  esp.reset();
  delay(500);
  while(!esp.ready());

  debugPort.println("ARDUINO: setup rest client");
  if(!rest.begin("MYAPI")) {
    debugPort.println("ARDUINO: failed to setup rest client");
    while(1);
  }

  /*setup wifi*/
  debugPort.println("ARDUINO: setup wifi");
  esp.wifiCb.attach(&wifiCb);
  esp.wifiConnect("MIWIFI","MIPASSWORD");
  debugPort.println("ARDUINO: system started");
}

void loop() {
  char response[266];
  esp.process();
  if(wifiConnected) {
    rest.get("/");
    if(rest.getResponse(response, 266) == HTTP_STATUS_OK){
      debugPort.println("RESPONSE: ");
      debugPort.println(response);
    }
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

When it runs I get this on the serial monitor:
~�~�~�~�~ instead of the text on the println

How can I see the text properly?